# What does the norm tell me in this function space?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, function-spaces

Consider the space of real functions $$ X:=\bigg\{e^{\frac{\log^2(s)}{\log(x)}}:x\in(0,1),s\in(0,1]\bigg\}. $$

The map $\rho:e^{\frac{\log^2(s)}{\log(x)}}\mapsto s$ is a way to associate a magnitude to each function in the space. So I guess this is the norm of the function space?

I read that the norm is a way to assign a positive real number to each function in the function space, so I think it is a norm.

> How does the norm I wrote tell me anything about the function space?

So from $X$'s vector space structure, if $s$ is real, then it's a 1-dimensional $\Bbb R$ vector space, and is the open real unit interval I think.

And I think the norm, $\rho$ gives the same information as the usual Euclidean metric on the open unit interval?

Comment: Can you say more about $X$? In what sense is it a space of functions, and not just numbers? I can't imagine $\rho$ passing the positive homogeneity test.

Comment: $X$ is a space of functions in the sense that $\exp(\log^2(.5)/\log(x))$ is one element in the space

Comment: also the domain and codomain are (0,1)

Comment: A norm is always defined on a vector space.  Is $X$ a vector space?